# Dynamically build a menu with a TableViewController in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am quite new to Objective-C and Xcode so I don't really know how to handle a dynamic menu with TableViews.

I am generating Table Rows and want to load an other ViewController by clicking at the rows.
I have tried to link the row to a NavigationController and wanted to load the furthers views there with:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Fremdbearbeitung"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but I have problems that the view is not in the view hierarchy at the moment. Also I don't know to tell there dynamically which instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier should be loaded by passing information from the rows.

Can you give me tips how to handle that best practice?
Can I tell the table rows at they are initialized where they should linked when they are clicked?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Found a way that works for me:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

testclass *test = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                              bundle:nil];
UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:test.second];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

So i can dynamically go to the view with identifier which i gave to the function in my object test and property second.

I don't need a extra navigation controller for that, because i can do that in my main TableView.

Is this a good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to push the viewController and not present it. It will push the view controller onto the navigation controller’s stack and updates the display.

Read the [Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313) clearly again. Also Learn about S[toryboards and segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457).

Also the [ViewController Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457).

Also you will find tons of tutorials for all the basics you want to learn, use Google like crazy..!

Edit :  [Using Storyboard Segues](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-storyboards/)

Comment: Thanks for bringing me on the right way. I have edited my question with my solution. What do you say?

Comment: @Jan-PhilippFischer , what you are doing now is right. But remember, if you have both of your controllers in the same storyboards, you should be using Segues and not instantiating the storyboard to get the controllers all the time. Checkout the link in the edited answer.